# Find what sessions student came in and didn't come in for

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find out which sessions the student came in for. This means getting a list of all sessions that have occurred and comparing them to whether the student came into this session or not.
I have 3 tables:
**attendance_record**

```
| session_id | student_id |    date    |   time   |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-03-07 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-03-14 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-03-21 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-03-28 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-04-04 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-04-11 | 16:05:02 |
|         52 |   17000004 | 2017-05-02 | 16:05:02 |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+`
```

**session**

```
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| session_id | module_id | staff_id | room_id |  day_of_week |  type       |  
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|         52 |         8 | 17000004 |      11 | Tuesday      | Lecture     |  
|         53 |         8 | 17000004 |      12 | Friday       | Lab         |  
|         53 |         8 | 17000004 |      12 | Friday       | Lab         |  
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------+`
```

**student**

```
+----------+---------+---------------------+--+
|   s_id   | s_name  |       s_email       |  |
+----------+---------+---------------------+--+
| 17000004 | student | student@student.com |  |
+----------+---------+---------------------+--+
```

**expected output**

```
+------------+---------+
|    date    | attended|
+------------+---------+
| 2017-02-14 |       0 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-02-21 |       0 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-02-28 |       0 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-03-07 |       1 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-03-14 |       1 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-03-21 |       1 |
+----------+-----------+
| 2017-03-28 |       1 |
+----------+-----------+
```

The query that I am trying to figure out is:
Find all the dates that have occurred for a module where module_id = 8 and session.type = 'Lecture'
and see if the student has attended this session.

Comment: You dont have `module_id = 7` in your data, only `8`. Is `@s_id` a parameter or you want show all student?

Comment: You need an aditional table to have all sesion dates, so you can validate if `attendance_record` match that sesion

Comment: What is the expected output based on your given data (assuming you want for module_id = 8)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: where you get date `2017-01-31` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i fixed my data now to reflect the question

Comment: Same problem where you get `2017-02-14` -  `02-21 02-28` Now you see why you need a table with sesions dates?

Answer (score 1):

First step should be to join the tables:

```
SELECT * from attendance_record as a inner join session as s 
  on a.session_id = s.session_id 
  inner join student as st 
  on a.student_id = st.s_id
```

On that you can query whatever you want

```
SELECT * from attendance_record as a inner join session as s 
  on a.session_id = s.session_id 
  inner join student as st 
  on a.student_id = st.s_id
  WHERE
  s.module_id = 7 
  AND 
  s.session_type = 'Lecture'
  AND 
  st.student_name = 'student'
```

if all you want is to know if he attended, just use `count(*)` and see if you get more than 0

Comment: I've made an "expected output" section, could i get that result from the query you have provided here?